# Why do the number of iterations matter while generating the random number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, random

I want to generate a random number using a given function `f1()`. I have the solution but I am unable to understand the number of iterations required(5 in this case) to generate the random number.

I tried reading other questions and answers but they focused on how to generate a random number(s), not on why a particular technique was followed.

This is my code:

```
import random


def f1():
    return(random.randint(0, 1))


def f29():
    while(1):
        Res = 0
        for _ in range(0, 5):
            Res = Res << 1 | f1()
        if(Res <= 29):
            return (Res)


print(f29())
```

I observed one thing: if I change the range of for loop from 5 to 4, only numbers below 20 were appearing, if I changed it to 3, only single digits were appearing. Maybe my observations are anecdotal. My aim is to generate a random number between 0 and 29, inclusive using f1() which generates a random integer: 0 or 1.

Comment: Do you know what `<<` does? It's a bitwise left shift. Now take the fact that `2 ** 5 == 32` and you have your solution.

Comment: So Res = Res << 1 | f1() allows you to a generate random number whose digits are created using f1().

Comment: @Matthias yeah, it shifts to the left by the specified number. And could you please elaborate on `Now take the fact that 2 ** 5 == 32 and you have your solution.`?

Comment: With a pen and paper, walk through your code keeping track of `Res`, `Res << 1`, `f1()`. and `Res << 1 | f1()` for each iteration - use a coin toss for `f()`.

Comment: `f1()` will give you `0` or `1`. For the maximum let's assume that it always gives us `1`. In the first loop `0 << 1 | 1` gives you `1`. Second loop: `1 << 1 | 1` -> `3`. Third loop `3 << 1 | 1` -> `7` and so on ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are summing the variable `Res` every iteration. Each iteration has the probability to increase `Res` by 1 bit if `f1()` returns 1.

If your  `f1()` always returns 1, the value will be:
iter 1: 1
iter 2: 3
iter 3: 7
iter 4: 15

That is why when you change your range from 5 to 4 you see only values below 20. The highest it can be is 15.